# Script to Remove a Letter at the End of some Directories

Tags: bash, directory, rename

Let's suppose I have a directory with this Structure:

[image]

I am making a script that removes the letter "x" in those cases when there is one at the end in order to have this:

[image]

So, I was thinking to do a For Loop that goes to each directory and then take the last part of the folder path

```
for d in Fruits_and_Vegetables/*/
do
     (cd "$d" && Fruit_or_Vegetable=`basename "$PWD"`)
done
```

The problem is that I am not sure how to tell to go and take only the last Directory

And then, I was thinking in modifying the string

```
echo $Fruit_or_Vegetable | awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}'  # substr(s, a, b) : it returns b number of chars from string s, starting at position a. 
                                                                      # The parameter b is optional, in which case it means up to the end of the string.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to tell AWK to consider "Moscato Giallox" as just one word, because when I execute the command it returns "Moscat Giallox" instead of "Moscato Giallo" .. also I guess I have to place an if statement to see if the last letter is x, and only execute the command in those cases.

Could you give me some suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the `rename` command? It allows you to use Perl-style regular expression matching and replacement.

Comment: @Barmar, different systems have different `rename` commands.  See [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/264812).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) and [`Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) parsing can make that pretty easy. Starting with your directory structure above:

```
$: find @(Fruits|Vegetables)
Fruits
Fruits/Grapes
Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape
Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape/Muscat Ottonel
Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape/Muscato Gallox
Fruits/Mangoes
Fruits/Mangoes/Ataulfo Mango
Fruits/Mangoes/Tommy Atkins Mangox
Vegetables
Vegetables/Potatoes
Vegetables/Potatoes/Ratte Potatox
Vegetables/Potatoes/Yukon Gold Potato
```

Code for the changes you want.

```
shopt -s extglob  # allow fancy @(...) construct to specify dirs
shopt -s globstar # add double-asterisk for flexible depth
for d in @(Fruits|Vegetables)/**/*x/ # *EDITED* - added trailing / for dirs only
do echo "mv \"$d\" \"${d%x/}/\" "   # show the command first
         mv "$d" "${d%x/}/"         # rename the dirs
done
```

Output from the `echo` statements:

```
mv "Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape/Muscato Gallox/" "Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape/Muscato Gallo/"
mv "Fruits/Mangoes/Tommy Atkins Mangox/" "Fruits/Mangoes/Tommy Atkins Mango/"
mv "Vegetables/Potatoes/Ratte Potatox/" "Vegetables/Potatoes/Ratte Potato/"
```

Result:

```
$: find @(Fruits|Vegetables)
Fruits
Fruits/Grapes
Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape
Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape/Muscat Ottonel
Fruits/Grapes/Muskat Grape/Muscato Gallo
Fruits/Mangoes
Fruits/Mangoes/Ataulfo Mango
Fruits/Mangoes/Tommy Atkins Mango
Vegetables
Vegetables/Potatoes
Vegetables/Potatoes/Ratte Potato
Vegetables/Potatoes/Yukon Gold Potato
```

Comment: The output is this: `mv "Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox" "Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox/" mv: cannot move 'Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox' to a subdirectory of itself, 'Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox/Moscato Giallox'`

Comment: did you enter `mv "$d" "${d%x/}/"` exactly?

Comment: try leaving off the last `/`: `mv "$d" "${d%x/}"` On my emulation it worked correctly, but `mv` has seemingly arcane rules for determining correct behavior. XD

Comment: I entered `mv "$d" "${d%x/}/"` exactly, I literally just copied and pasted .. maybe is the way I am executing the script, I have had problems with that in the past .. I am using #!/bin/bash .. and I am executing it as `./renaming_names.sh`

Comment: leaving off the last `/` this happens: `mv "Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox" "Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox" mv: cannot move 'Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox' to a subdirectory of itself, 'Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallox/Moscato Giallox'`

Comment: I think I missed a trailing slash on the `for` line. Add that and see if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the misfire. :)